# Building auto-increment in SQL Server on legacy data using varchar

Tags: sql-server

Say I am redesigning a database with 5 columns, and someone before me thought it was a good idea to do the following:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
------------------------
a    a    c    d    a_a_c_d
a    b    c    d    a_b_c_d
b    a    c    d    b_a_c_d
b    b    c    d    b_b_c_d
c    a    c    d    c_a_c_d
c    b    c    d    c_b_c_d
```

Where col5 is referenced as a foreign key by other tables.

In addition to creating a unique int ID per row, I want to remove Col4.

I cannot oversee the size of the refactor if I have to replace all references by my new unique ID. Theoretically, can I keep legacy references in tact, and automatically give new entries in Col5 a meaningless incrementing varchar, comparable to `identity(1,1)` (e.g. `Foo1`, `Foo2`, etc.)?

Comment: So you want keep `Col5` as varchar but instead of auto fill with `Col1+Col2+ Col3` you want get a autonumeric string?

Comment: This is - for sure - not the best way, being honest it's quite ugly, but - if you think about keeping Col5 as `varchar` key why not keep it 
*as is*?

Comment: How is col5 filled at the moment? Is a persistant computed column, is it a trigger or SP-logic?

Comment: One risk I see is if there is an application somewhere that is trying to parse out the foreign keys it's getting out of one of the other tables - e.g., the application actually cares about the `b` in `c_b_c_d`.  Then it will fail when it tries to parse `Foo57`.

Comment: @Shnugo I cannot keep it as is because Col4 will completely disappear in the new design (and keeping it and filling it with dummy data seems like an even worse idea). (@criticalfix, I am not afraid of this, because I will rebuild the logic). However, I want to do refactor step by step if I can, and not everything at once, so after everything else is done, I can replace all references to the new 'ID' column, and remove 'Col5'. Or is that unwise?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes, for any new records after data migration

Comment: @DaniëlCamps Please answer: How is this value created / set ?

Comment: @Shnugo I am not quite sure (hence the redesign). It is currently in a Microsoft Access application with a **Big Ball of Mud** pattern. My guess is that the values of the other columns are manually concatenated in the query which inserts records, but finding it is no trivial task.

Comment: @DaniëlCamps *lol* I will note this as the *BBoM* pattern, one of the most often used design patterns in the wild :-) One approach might be to copy the data into a well designed table with a different name and use a `VIEW` with the former name (evtl. with schema binding) for the legacy code to continue working...

Comment: @Shnugo I will go with Juan's answer, as it will make it easier to completely get rid of the column on the mid-long term, but thank you for your ideas (and sympathy) are duly noted ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because looks like you are going to get rid of `Col5` anyway I would just create a new `Col6`

```
ALTER TABLE [yourTable] ADD [Col6] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

And create a new `after insert trigger` to update `Col5` with the new created value from `Col6`.

Comment: Seems fitting, especially since I want to add a unique int ID anyway. Do I have to take type casting into account for this, or does SQL Server understand that an INT can become a VARCHAR?

Comment: Yes, you can update a varchar field with an integer without problem. check this http://rextester.com/UVSU36307

Comment: Perfect, and nice that you added an example